# Why is this map a split monomorphism?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

I have  a question regarding a lemma in the proof of  Hopkins-Neeman Correspondence.
It is the beginning  part of Lemma 1.2 in the [The Chromatic Tower for D(R)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/004093839290047L)

Let $Y$ be an object of the derived category of bounded complexes of finitely generated projectives over $R$.

The author claims there is a natural morphism, $R \to Y \otimes Y^{*}$.

I think the map he is talking about is the one corresponding to the identity under the isomorphism, $Hom(X, Y) \cong Hom(R, X^{*} \otimes Y)$.

But I am unable to understand the next claim:

If $\alpha : R \to k$ is a homorphism where $R$ is a Noetherian ring and $k$ is a field then if  $ker(\alpha) \in Supp(Y)$ then

$f \otimes k : k \to  Y \otimes Y^* \otimes k$ is a  split monomorphism.

Can anyone help me see this?

Comment: The object $k$ is a field, therefore $Y \otimes Y^* \otimes k$ has a natural structure of $k$-vector space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me elaborate on what Leo says.

The morphism $f\otimes k$ lives in the derived category of bounded complexes of finite-dimensional $k$-vector spaces, which is equivalent to the category of globally finite-dimensional graded $k$-vector spaces. The equivalence is given by the cohomology functor. Since $Y$ is a bounded complex of finitely generated projective $R$-modules, we have
$$H^n(Y\otimes Y^*\otimes k)=\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}H^{i+n}(Y\otimes k)\otimes H^{i}(Y\otimes k)^*,\qquad n\in\mathbb{Z}.$$
If $\{e_j\}_{j\in J}$ denotes a global basis of $H^{*}(Y\otimes k)$, the morphism
$$f\otimes\alpha\colon k\longrightarrow\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}H^{i}(Y\otimes k)\otimes H^{i}(Y\otimes k)^*$$
is defined by
$$1\mapsto \sum_{j\in J}e_j\otimes e_j^*.$$
Since $\dim k=1$, $f\otimes \alpha$ is either injective or trivial. Moreover, it is trivial if and only if the basis $\{e_j\}_{j\in J}$ is empty. We now use the hypothesis: this basis is non-empty becuase $H^{*}(Y\otimes k)\neq 0$ since $\ker\alpha$ is in the support of $Y$.